# Change text between tags to uppercase java

Tags: java, tags, case

I need to change text between tags to upper case in a string and then print the whole string with the changed letters. So

```
"asdasd <upcase>something</upcase> dfldkflskdf <upcase>stuff</upcase>skdlskd" would become: 
"asdasd SOMETHING dfldkflskdf STUFF skdlskd"
```

So far I got this but it returns the text only from the first ocurrence of the tags.

```
static String tags (String word)
    {
        String changed = word;

        while (changed.indexOf("<upcase>" ) >= 0)
                {
                changed = (changed.substring(changed.indexOf("<upcase>")+"<upcase>".length(),changed.indexOf("</upcase>")));
                }
        return changed.toUpperCase();
```

Comment: Aside from the question, should you not be using an XML parser?

Comment: I know I should be but its an exercise Im trying to solve.

Comment: You're close, you need to keep track of the position of where `</upcase>` is, and then use `str.indexOf("<upcase>", startPos)`.

Answer (score 0):

First, since you can have more than one string between the upcase tags, you need to return a collection of Strings.  I chose a List.

Second, you need to use the String indexOf(string, pos) method, so you don't lose your place in the XML string.

Here's one way to do what you want.

```
public List<String> tags(String xml) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    String startTag = "<upcase>";
    String endTag = "</upcase>";
    int sPos = xml.indexOf(startTag);
    while (sPos >= 0) {
        int ePos = xml.indexOf(endTag, sPos + startTag.length());
        if (ePos >= 0) {
            list.add(xml.substring(sPos + startTag.length(), ePos)
                    .toUpperCase());
        }
        sPos = xml.indexOf(startTag, ePos + endTag.length());
    }
    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All right, here is an updated version:

```
public static String tags(String xml) {
    final String upcaseTagRegex = "<upcase>(.*?)</upcase>";
    String result = xml;
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(upcaseTagRegex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(xml);

    while(matcher.find()) {
        result = result.replaceFirst(upcaseTagRegex, matcher.group(1).toUpperCase());
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I didnt ask the question properly, I edited it now. the regex way prints the tags too. I need to print the whole changed string without the tags.

Comment: Oh yeah! There is a bug with the greedy regex.